# Problems using cuminc() to plot latency to event

Tags: plot, latency

I'm trying to plot a graph of latency to an event (lat_EE), with proportion of animals on the y and time on the x axis.

My data looks like this:

```
animal     Cond Iso Order lat_sed lat_rec dur_anes lat_EE
  74 Vagotomy   1     B      NA      NA       NA  2.558
  77     Sham   1     B      NA      NA       NA  2.093
  90 Vagotomy   1     B      NA      NA       NA  2.305
 100 Vagotomy   1     B   8.504   10.93   2.4231  1.601    
 105     Sham   1     B   9.013   10.45   1.4404  1.932
```

Where the lat_EE is already calculated. Let's say 100% of my animals had such event by 5 min, for some reason the plot only shows that 50% have by that time.

This is the code I am using:

```
latEE1 = cuminc(alldata1$lat_EE, alldata1$Cond, alldata1$Iso)
latEE1
plot(latEE1,color=1:6,xlab="Time (min)", ylab="Proportion of animals", xlim=c(0,20),     ylim(0,1))
```

Comment: I think perhaps it is taking all the animals (vagotomy and sham) as 100% as opposed to each Cond being 100% on its own.

Comment: I have figured out how to have it run properly as two plots, one for vagotomy and one for sham. Trying to overlay them below does not work    plot(latEEs, latEEvx, color=1:6,xlab="Time (min)", ylab="Proportion of animals", xlim=c(0,20), ylim(0,1))